# How to always apply focusVisible styling on a focused Material-UI Button component?

Tags: css, reactjs, button, material-ui, focus

For a Material-UI Button component, I would like to have the "focus" styling look the same as "focusVisible" styling. Meaning I want it to have the same ripple effect visible if the button was focused programatically or with the mouse as if the button was focused with the tab key.

A sort-of workaround I have found is to call `dispatchEvent(new window.Event("keydown"))` on the element before it is focused, causing keyboard to be the last input type used. This will have the effect of making the button look the way I want UNTIL the onMouseLeave event (from MUI <ButtonBase/>) or another mouse event is fired, causing the visible focus to disappear.

I have figured out how to change the focus styling of the component like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button"

const styles = {
  root: {
    '&:focus': {
      border: "3px solid #000000"
    }
  }
}

const CustomButtonRaw = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { classes, ...rest } = props
  return <Button classes={{root: classes.root}} {...rest} ref={ref}/>
}

const CustomButton = withStyles(styles, { name: "CustomButton" })(CustomButtonRaw)

export default CustomButton
```

So, I can apply some style to the button when it is in "focus" state. (For ex. I applied a border). But I am missing how to get the styles to apply. I have tried putting the className 'Mui-visibleFocus' on the Button but that did not seem to have an effect. Is there some way to get the styles that would be applied if the Button was in visibleFocus state?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, it's a pity that still doesn't work

Comment: [Think Blew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15621733) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67073530) saying "Tried this and came up with a solution using action ref of Buttonbase [https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-dialog-button-autofocus-y9hfz](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-dialog-button-autofocus-y9hfz)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ButtonBase` (which `Button` [delegates to](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.2/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L295)) has an [action prop](https://material-ui.com/api/button-base/#props) which provides the ability to [set the button's focus-visible state](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.2/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js#L107).

`ButtonBase` leverages the [useImperativeHandle hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) for this. To leverage it, you pass a ref into the `action` prop and then you can later call `actionRef.current.focusVisible()`.

However, this by itself is not sufficient, because there are several mouse and touch events that [ButtonBase listens to](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.2/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js#L136) in order to start/stop the ripple. If you use the `disableTouchRipple` prop, it [prevents ButtonBase from trying to start/stop the ripple based on those events](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.2/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js#L127).

Unfortunately `disableTouchRipple` prevents click and touch animations on the button. These can be restored by adding another `TouchRipple` element explicitly that you control. My example below shows handling `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` as a proof-of-concept, but an ideal solution would deal with all the different events that `ButtonBase` handles.

Here's a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TouchRipple from "@material-ui/core/ButtonBase/TouchRipple";

const FocusRippleButton = React.forwardRef(function FocusRippleButton(
  { onFocus, onMouseDown, onMouseUp, children, ...other },
  ref
) {
  const actionRef = React.useRef();
  const rippleRef = React.useRef();
  const handleFocus = (event) => {
    actionRef.current.focusVisible();
    if (onFocus) {
      onFocus(event);
    }
  };
  const handleMouseUp = (event) => {
    rippleRef.current.stop(event);
    if (onMouseUp) {
      onMouseUp(event);
    }
  };
  const handleMouseDown = (event) => {
    rippleRef.current.start(event);
    if (onMouseDown) {
      onMouseDown(event);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Button
      ref={ref}
      action={actionRef}
      disableTouchRipple
      onFocus={handleFocus}
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      {...other}
    >
      {children}
      <TouchRipple ref={rippleRef} />
    </Button>
  );
});
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FocusRippleButton variant="contained" color="primary">
        Button 1
      </FocusRippleButton>
      <br />
      <br />
      <FocusRippleButton
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onFocus={() => console.log("Some extra onFocus functionality")}
      >
        Button 2
      </FocusRippleButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Unconditional focus ripple]

Comment: Hi Ryan, this is excellent and does just what I asked. But there is one problem with using this solution of applying 'disableTouchRipple' prop: Now the button doesn't have click animations anymore. Do you know of a way for me to access the 'rippleRef' from ButtonBase so that I can trigger the ripple myself? Or is there a workaround to get click animations working again?

Comment: You get a click animation in the sense that the focus ripple immediately starts when you click; though I realize it isn't the same -- clicking on a button that already has focus doesn't provide any feedback. I couldn't find a way to get the focus ripple to work for clicks without `disableTouchRipple` (I tried several ways).

Comment: Material-UI doesn't expose any way to access `rippleRef`. If you attempt to pass it via `TouchRippleProps`, then it breaks `ButtonBase` since it loses access to the `rippleRef`. I don't see any way to do it without changes to Material-UI.

Comment: It seems you are right. I've been trying to find a way to access the `rippleRef` but I don't think there is one... That's unfortunate. Now I am wondering, is it possible to use a separate `<TouchRipple/>` element to create the animation myself?

Comment: @user3044553 Yes, it is possible to add a separate `<TouchRipple>` element for the click animation. I've updated my answer to include an overly-simplistic (doesn't deal with all the events that `ButtonBase` handles) version of this.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a reference to the `action` of the material-ui `Button` component and use the action reference within `useLayoutEffect` to achieve the ripple effect

```
import React, { createRef, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

function FocusButton(props) {
  const { handleClose } = props;

  const actionRef = createRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (actionRef.current) {
      actionRef.current.focusVisible();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Button action={actionRef} onClick={handleClose}>
      Ok
    </Button>
  );
}
```

The above `FocusButton` can be used as a replacement to `Button` or simply you can add a reference and call the `focusVisible()` in the trigger method

Eg:

```
const buttonRef = createRef();

const handleButton2Click = () => {
    buttonRef.current.focusVisible();
};

.
.
.
.

<Button action={buttonRef} variant="outlined">
        Button 1
</Button>

<Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleButton2Click}>
        Button 2
</Button>
```

You can find the demo in this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-dialog-button-autofocus-y9hfz?file=/demo.js)